If I sell a put option that expires ITM on the ex-dividend date, do I get the dividend?
Say I sell a put option committing to buy X stock at $50 on Y date. Y date is also the ex-dividend date. The put option expires in the money, so the option buyer will exercise the option and I end up with the stock. Do I get the dividend in this case?

In order to be eligible to receive the dividend, you must own the stock before the ex dividend date.
Since your short in-the-money put expires at the end of the day, you will not be eligible for the dividend because you do not own the stock in time to qualify for the dividend.

So if the put expires the day before the ex-dividend date, I will qualify for the dividend?

In order to qualify for the dividend, you must own the stock before it goes ex-dividend.  Therefore, you must be assigned the day before the ex-div date.

No - stocks bought on or after the ex-div date do not get the dividend.  The price of the put should account for the price drop on the ex-div date.

What is the relevance of the put accounting for the price drop on the ex-date if the option is going to expire at the end of the day?

My intuition was that the OP thinks they are either getting a free lunch (paying the lower stock price and getting the dividend) or getting robbed (paying the higher price and not getting the dividend), when in reality the lower price after the dividend is already accounted for in the value of the option even before the ex-div date.

Perhaps.  The dividend is reflected in the put's price but that doesn't mean that the put seller benefits from 'all' of it.
